# Blank Background

Tags: html, image, text

I have created an HTML with background for my bullet points.

I enter text for it.  When I send it to email addresses that entire background is missing.

However, when I take out the text it's fine. The bullet point background is there.  It's almost like the background is in the foreground and covering up that text.

Here's part of the source code:

```
<tr>
   <td width="600" valign="top" background="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg" height="250px" padding:40px="" name="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg" contentid="57e93b50-13b0bf80bae-b72427ac28f4177bd55290ce12678282" xt="SPIMAGE" spname="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg">
      <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:350px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:1;' src="<img%20src="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg" name="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg" contentid=57e93b50-13b0bf80bae-b72427ac28f4177bd55290ce12678282 xt="SPIMAGE" SPNAME="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg">"/>
      <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:254px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:2;'>
         <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;"></p>
         <p style="padding:50px  100px 0 100px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#ffffff; padding:30px  000px 00px 100px;font-weight:bold;">This is </p>
         <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#ffffff;padding:00px  00px 00px 100px;font-weight:bold;">my list:</p>
         <ul style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px; color:#ffffff; padding:00px  00px 00px 100px;line-height:32px; margin:15px 0 0 0;">
                    <li>List 1</li>
                    <li>List 2</li>
                    <li>List 3</li>
                    <li>List 4</li>
         </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either upload you background image to service like `imgur.com` (or any image hosting service) and reference bg image from there, or properly embed the image in the message you sending. Otherwise you refer to image which is local to your machine.

Comment: I used that site and it looked good in the preview. However, when I sent a test mailing, I received this error :Exception:Failed to copy file, source: /app/content/marketer/private/content/2012/43848/11/18/1f8bf60e-13b155d3575-5fb2bd720d5cf67c7bdb5a02a7e699d8.jpg Destination: /app/content/marketer/shared/ra/2012/43848/11/40564719/http://i.imgur.com/eo18e.jpg

Comment: what about doing this right in first place? you upload image via their web interface. Once uploaded you get many links to access the image. One is direct like `http://imgur.com/dsfsdf.jpg`. You put this in your html as `src` here `<img ... src="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg" .../>` and that's it.

Comment: Yes, I did that. After that I got that error.  Here's the latest codes I'm using with Imgur hosting:

Comment: <td width="600" valign="top" background="http://i.imgur.com/eo18e.jpg" height="250px" contentid="1f8bf60e-13b155b9891-5fb2bd720d5cf67c7bdb5a02a7e699d8" src="1f8bf60e-13b155b9891-5fb2bd720d5cf67c7bdb5a02a7e699d8" spname="1f8bf60e-13b155b9891-5fb2bd720d5cf67c7bdb5a02a7e699d8"

Comment: xt="SPIMAGE" name="http://i.imgur.com/eo18e.jpg" padding:40px=""><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:350px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:1;' src="<img%20src="http://i.imgur.com/eo18e.jpg" name="http://i.imgur.com/eo18e.jpg" contentid=1f8bf60e-13b155b9891-5fb2bd720d5cf67c7bdb5a02a7e699d8 xt="SPIMAGE" SPNAME="thanksgiving-template-bullets.jpg">"/>
<v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"

Comment: id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:254px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:2;'>
<![endif]-->

Comment: When I changed src tp the proper path, it also gives me the long numbers after I save.

Comment: While posting code in comments please always add single backticks ` around it or SO will parse it and output may be different (i.e. ` code ` => `code`)